# How to restart flink from a savepoint from within the code

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a java class that is submitting a sql files to flink cluster.

I have

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();


streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.AT_LEAST_ONCE);
            streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
            streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setExternalizedCheckpointCleanup(
                    CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);

streamExecutionEnvironment.enableCheckpointing(5000, CheckpointingMode.AT_LEAST_ONCE);
        streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage(customParams.get("checkpoint_path"));

Configuration config = new Configuration();
config = new Configuration();
config.set(ExecutionCheckpointingOptions.ENABLE_CHECKPOINTS_AFTER_TASKS_FINISH, true);
config.set(PipelineOptions.NAME, customParams.get("pipeline_name"));

if (restartFromSavepointPath != null) {
    config.set(SAVEPOINT_PATH, restartFromSavepointPath);
}

streamExecutionEnvironment.setStateBackend(new EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend(true));
streamExecutionEnvironment.configure(config);
...
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(streamExecutionEnvironment);

tableEnv.executeSql("create table ....");

// this is end of the main class
```

For getting `restartFromSavepointPath` I have some code that can get the latest checkpoint location, I can see the value as `file:///tmp/flink-checkpoint-directory-domain/a98c68e3139041bc32e6a931e1f701e1/chk-24/_metadata`

When i package the above code as fat jar and run it, the job does NOT start from the above checkpoint.
command to start is `flink run -c com.some.Deployer /some/local/location/some.jar` --> **How to i get this to start from the savepoint (given the `execution.savepoint.path` is set via config.set(SAVEPOINT_PATH, restartFromSavepointPath);) ?**

But if i use `-s` option for `flink run -c com.some.Deployer -s file:///tmp/flink-checkpoint-directory-domain/a98c68e3139041bc32e6a931e1f701e1/chk-24/_metadata /some/local/location/some.jar` --> this one start the job from the savepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can set "execution.savepoint.path" in flink-conf.yaml to the latest path and it would take care. Also you can set "execution.savepoint.ignore-unclaimed-state" set to "false", so that it will not start if it is not restored from specified savepoint, if that is set to true, it will try to restore from savepoint, if failed it will start normally.
If you are using flink kubernetes operator, you can set "initialSavepointPath" in FlinkDeployment yaml in job spec as below:

```
  job:
jarURI: {{ .Values.jarName }} 
parallelism: {{ .Values.parallelism }}
entryClass: {{ .Values.entryClass }}
initialSavepointPath: {{ .Values.restorePath }}
```

you can replace values.restorePath with your savepoint location.

May I know how you are getting latest savepoint path, programatically

Comment: > May I know how you are getting latest savepoint path, programatically - 
You can get it via REST API - `/jobs/:jobid/savepoints/:triggerid`, see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/rest_api/#jobs-jobid-savepoints-triggerid. If you are stopping a job from java app using job client - JobClient.stopWithSavepoint returns the savepoint path as well

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `config.set(SAVEPOINT_PATH, checkpointPath);` where `config` is Configuration and `checkpointPath` is path to the latest `_metadata` file in aws s3

Comment: don't know if it worked in previous versions, but it doesn't work since 1.17+. SAVEPOINT_PATH option is ignored in the remote env setup, you need to provide SavepointRestoreSettings explicitly on remote env creation.

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do is run a flink job via a remote environment from a savepoint.

It is actually possible, i.e:

```java
SavepointRestoreSettings restoreSettings = SavepointRestoreSettings.forPath("/savepoints/savepoint-1234", false, RestoreMode.NO_CLAIM);
env = new RemoteStreamEnvironment(remoteHost, remotePort, Configuration.fromMap(Map.of()), new String[] {}, null, restoreSettings);
StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, settings);
...
tableEnv.executeSql("create table ....")
```

But you need to understand the difference between a remote env approach and a Rest API approach.
With the Rest API approach, you are submitting a job with a savepoint path from a remote, i.e. `curl https://flink-cluster/jars/:jarid/run -d '{"savepintPath": "<savepointPath>"}'` means that `<savepointPath>` is a path that a job will be trying to read during execution (building a job graph) on a remote flink cluster.

The remote env approach is different since you are actually submitting an already built job graph to a remote cluster, therefore reading a savepoint file happens on a client.

In practice, that means that the remote env approach requires your setup to provide some shared access to savepoints from both a remote flink cluster and a local client that submits a job to a cluster. Smth like using a shared predefined s3 folder should work, i.e.

flink cluster config (flink-conf.yaml):

```yaml
state.savepoints.dir: s3://savepoints/
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://checkpoints/
```

local client:

```java
SavepointRestoreSettings restoreSettings = SavepointRestoreSettings.forPath("s3://savepoints/savepoint-1234", false, RestoreMode.NO_CLAIM);
env = new RemoteStreamEnvironment(remoteHost, remotePort, Configuration.fromMap(Map.of()), new String[] {}, null, restoreSettings);
StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, settings);
...
tableEnv.executeSql("create table ....")
```

Answer (score -1):

If your want to use savepoint, when you stop or cancel job you must set savepoint;
then you can run with savepoint.

```
bin/flink stop --type [native/canonical] --savepointPath [:targetDirectory] :jobId
```

Comment: I understand that u can use `--savepointPath` with flink command. But i want an option for setting this within my java program, using `config.set(SAVEPOINT_PATH, restartFromSavepointPath);` Here `SAVEPOINT_PATH` value is  `execution.savepoint.path`. Is this possible.
My job is running multiple `insert into ...` statement, each of this is a separate job in flink, each of it needs to start from a different savepoint.